# How can I read an output from a while true process in console?

Tags: perl, printing, stdout

For the code

```
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host);
$ssh->login($user, $pass);
my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd);
print "STDOUT: $stdout STDERR: $stderr EXIT: $exit";
```

If my $cmd is "ls", then $stdout can have a correct output.

However, if my $cmd is "perl whileTrue.pl", then how can I have the output while running the perl? In whileTrue.pl, it will print my input in console.

Because if I not ssh to run it, the output will print to the console. However, when I ssh it, I cannot see my output until I really end this process.

Can I have something like flush concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like [`register_handler`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aPerl#%24ssh-%3Eregister_handler%28%24packet_type,_%24subref_%5b,_@args_%5d%29) method allows for non-blocking processing of the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aOpenSSH) instead of Net::SSH::Perl:

```
use Net::OpenSSH;
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, user => $user, password => $pass);
$ssh->system($cmd);
```